# Dead or Alive: Dimensions Control Mechanism

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, dead-or-alive-dimensions

In the recently released title for the Nintendo 3DS, some of the video previews seem to suggest that the characters are controlled by "selecting" combinations on the touch screen, rather than in the traditional manner for beat'em'ups.

Is this the case? Does DOA:Dimensions not have "normal" controls?

Comment: If this game is anything like the other games in the series, it's a "Fighting" game, not a "Beat 'em up".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that it's out, this can be answered definitively.

In DoAD, you can perform combos the old-fashioned way, or by tapping it on the bottom screen. If you're playing with buttons, the bottom screen highlights your combo sequence(s) as you enter the commands. Overall I find the user interface much nicer than Street Fighter's.

Unlike Street Fighter IV, there is no segregation between touchscreen / button control in online play. If someone is entering commands with the touchscreen an icon pops up on their side of the screen, so you know if they're doing it, but you can't forbid it like you can in SFIV. Realistically this probably doesn't matter, but some portions of the Internet are up in arms about it.

Answer (score 2):

Both the 3DS versions of DoA: Dimensions and Street Fighter IV seem to be making use of a control method similar to this. Note that it's *in addition* to normal controls though. So you can still play the game completely manually if you prefer, but there's the option of touching the special move "shortcuts" on the screen as well.

Comment: Having played SSF4, the controls come in handy. I do enjoy fighters on home consoles and at first I thought the idea of using a touch pad seemed cheap. It still feels kind of cheap but there are "cooldowns" for tapping moves on the touchpad which makes this style less cheap. As for DOA, it looks like it will play exactly like the consoles, just a little bit of ease by adding touchscreen controls since a full controller is out of the question. /rant. sorry :S